# Recommendations for serverless web app Data migration

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, umzug

I'm building a serverless web application using: API-gateway, S3, DynamoDB, Cloud Formation, ... I have come to a point where I'm adding a new feature that requires some data in S3 and DynamoDB to be migrated. I could of course write a one-off script that would do the job, but I was wondering if there are any good structural solutions out there?

I found https://github.com/sequelize/umzug but didn't look any deeper yet. Any reviews?

I'm particularly interested to learn how a data migration might work where there is an infrastructure change, e.g. data in one S3 bucket is migrated into a new S3 Bucket and a DynamoDB table. Anybody has some experience with this?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In general we have "Data Migration Service" and "Schema conversion tool" to migrate between different DB engines.  Also look at "AWS Data Pipeline" ..

To answer your question; it will depend on your requirements. To give you few examples; you can directly migrate data from one S3 bucket to other using a AWS CLI command "aws s3 cp" if there is no conversion needed in between. for example: You can copy data from S3 to redshift using "copy" command.

Comment: I'm more looking for a solution that can manage the different migrations that are created in the lifetime of an application. I worked with Ruby on Rails in the past which has this type of migration management.

Comment: are u talking about application migration ( from one technology stack to other ) or data migration (one db store to other ) ?

Comment: Data migration. e.g. you have a DynamoDB table containing users. Up to now all your users were of the same type, but now you want to have a property type for each user. You could catch it in the code, but it's nice to add property type=standard to the existing users. So you write a small script to do the migration of the DynamoDB table. After some time you have many versions of you schema and many scripts to convert them. RoR has a way to manage these versions. This might be interesting if you want to restore an old backup, ...

Comment: Got it.. You looking for something like this? https://dbmstools.com/version-control-tools

Comment: Yes these Migration-based is what I mean, but for when the data is in S3 and DynamoDB,...

Comment: @Karel did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @fischermatte I'm writing one-off scripts at this point, so not really...